# is the following in Conjunctive Normal Form?

Tags: logic

is ~(A+B) . (B+C) in CNF? I am particularly confused whether a term that is a sum, i.e., A+B that is wholly negated a term in CNf

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Try $\bar A \cdot \bar B \cdot (B + C)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please use MathJax. You may find a tutorial here: [https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, negation can only be applied to literals in CNF and DNF.  You need to apply the De Morgan laws to simplify it.

Comment: But simplifying it would mean ~(A+B) = (~A.~B) and the resultant expression would be (~A.~B).(B+C)

Comment: If you think of it as ~A.~B.(B+C), then that's CNF.

Comment: @Mathew Daly Thank you so much. Had been a while since I had done Boolean algebra and I absolutely missed that.

Answer (score 0):

No. Negations can only occur in front of atomic statements in order for a statement to be in CNF.